# Firebase dynamic links not working on first install for iOS <= 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am having trouble getting dynamic links to work on first install for iOS <= 9.

Steps

- I have the link in "Notes" app
- I click on the link, it opens in Safary and correctly redirects to the AppStore
- I install the app for the first time and open it and receive no callback in AppDelegate for iOS 8. For iOS 9+ the "dynamicLink" is nil.

Additional Info:

- All delegate methods from docs are implemented but none is called (they work if the app is already installed)
- both custom and bundle id schemes are setup in "URL types"
- Associated domains are enabled and I have "applinks:dyz22.app.goo.gl" in it, although it shouldn't matter for an iOS 8
- Google plist is there
- The team ID is setup in the dashboard (App ID Prefix), although I haven't seen it anywhere in the Google plist, don't know if it should be there
- it works for 10+
- FIRApp is configured in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"
- Have tried with C++ SDK as well, but got the same result.

Comment: have u solved this problem, please lemme know

Comment: @AnuragBhakuni sorry for the late response, I've retried for the iOS 9 and it worked correctly. Don't know exactly what was previously wrong. Maybe the newer Firebase SDK that I've tried, or they've changed somthing server side, or I might have missed something .

I still have the problem for iOS 8